# Are there pre-compiled binaries of zxing for Windows

Tags: zxing, binaries

Is there a pre-compiled version of [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) for Windows? Both the Java version or the C++ port will do. I could find source packages on their site.

Answer (score 0):

The Java artifacts for `core` and `javase` are available in Maven, from Sonatype's OSS repo: https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~zxing

This is of use if you're using Maven, but also means you can grab .jar files over the web too:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/google/com/google/zxing/